# Laravel checkbox filter ajax

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel

I need to realize a checkbox filter for vacancies based on ajax. So I have some categories on page, and when user marks some checkboxes the result block shows only vacancies in selected categories. If there are no selected checkboxes page shows all vacancies in all categories.

Now I have my current variant, but it doesnt work with array of checkboxes values, and every time after loading results checkboxes states are resetting.

What I have now:

My html markup

```
    <div class="category">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="cat1" value="1" style="display: none;">
        <label for="cat1" class='cat-check'>Category-1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="cat2" value="2" style="display: none;">
        <label for="cat2" class='cat-check'>Category-2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="cat3" value="3" style="display: none;">
        <label for="cat3" class='cat-check'>Category-3</label>
    </div>
```

This is my search.js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(':checkbox').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var cat = $(':checkbox:checked').val();

            $.post('/vacancies/searchcat', {cat: cat}, function(markup)
            {
                $('#search-results').html(markup);
            });            

        console.log(cat);

        });

});
```

Controller

```
    public function searchcat()
{

    $cat = \Input::get('cat');

    $cat = (int) $cat;

    $vacancies = \Vacancy::where('category_id', '=', $cat)->get();

    return \View::make('vacancies.empty')->with('vacancies', $vacancies); 

}
```

and route

```
Route::post('/vacancies/searchcat', 'SearchController@searchcat');
```

Mb you now some workable examples for my situation.

**UPDATE 2 NEW .JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var categories = [];

// Listen for 'change' event, so this triggers when the user clicks on the checkboxes labels
$('input[name="category[]"]').on('change', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    categories = []; // reset 

    $('input[name="category[]"]:checked').each(function()
    {
        categories.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.post('/vacancies/searchcat', {categories: categories}, function(markup)
    {
        $('#search-results').html(markup);
        var count = $('#count').val(); // vacancies count, from hidden input   
        $(".page-title").html("(" + count + ")");            
    });            

});
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, give your checkboxes all the same name (array notation) and a value:

```html
<div class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="1" id="cat1" style="display: none">
    <label for="cat1" class='cat-check'>Category-1</label>
</div>
<div class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="2" id="cat2" style="display: none;">
    <label for="cat2" class='cat-check'>Category-2</label>
</div>
<div class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="3" id="cat3" style="display: none;">
    <label for="cat3" class='cat-check'>Category-3</label>
</div>
```

In search.js, loop over all checked checkboxes and collect the values in an array. This array will then be posted to the server:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var categories = [];

    // Listen for 'change' event, so this triggers when the user clicks on the checkboxes labels
    $('input[name="cat[]"]').on('change', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        categories = []; // reset 

        $('input[name="cat[]"]:checked').each(function()
        {
            categories.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.post('/vacancies/searchcat', {categories: categories}, function(markup)
        {
            $('#search-results').html(markup);
        });            

    });

});
```

In your controller method, you can fetch the categories array and build a `where in` query:

```php
public function searchcat()
{
    $categories = \Input::get('categories');

    $vacancies = \Vacancy::whereIn('category_id', $categories)->get();

    return \View::make('vacancies.empty')->with('vacancies', $vacancies); 
}
```

Comment: It works, but it shows only vacancies from 1 category, when I mark second checkbox it shows records only from 2nd category. Seems like page refreshes and it is loosing values from previous checkbox. How is it possible to implement the multiple selection ?

Comment: UPDATE: Just added the submit button, and everything works fine with it, but I need to do this filter without submit button.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to fulfill your requirements. I changed the click event on `$('input[name="cat[]"]')` to a change event. I just realized your checkboxes are hidden in your example, so now the event triggers even if you click the checkboxes labels.

Comment: Everything works fine, but I cant understand why ajax is sending always 2 posts requests instead of 1 ?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide some more code (the JS part)?

Comment: Post 1 Updated with my JS

Comment: Hmm, i cannot see why the ajax request should be fired two times. How did you find out about that?