# filter product by checkbox in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm building a website using Laravel framework
I want to use the checkbox to filter products by category for display

blade.php:

```
<ul>
@foreach($category as $val)
<li>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cat_{{$val->id}}" name="cat[]" value="{{$val->title_en}}">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="cat_{{$val->id}}">{{ $val->title_fa }}</label>
    </div>
</li>
 @endforeach
```

js:

```
var categories = [];

// Listen for 'change' event, so this triggers when the user clicks on the checkboxes labels
$('input[name="cat[]"]').on('change', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    categories = []; // reset

    $('input[name="cat[]"]:checked').each(function()
    {
        categories.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },

        type:'POST',

        url: '/test',

        data:{categories,_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },

        success:function(data){

            alert(categories);

        }

    });
```

route:

```
Route::post('/test', 'IndexController@serachCat');
```

IndexController:

```
public function searchCat()
{
    dd('search');
}
```

Using these codes I only get the alert name when selecting a category, but I want to go to the controller after selecting a category and filter the products there and then display them

What changes should I make to the codes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel checkbox filter ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414103/laravel-checkbox-filter-ajax)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, Have you tried to search for the thing you want?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to return a json response to work with data after ajax has successfully worked.

```
Route::post('/test/{option}', 'IndexController@serachCat');
```

.

```
public function searchCat($option)
{
    $cat=Model::where('option',$option)->get()
    return response()->json(['categoryData'=>$cat],200);
}
```

.

```
url: '/test/'+data,
```

Comment: It's not like that only json should be return from the controller, you can also return html or rendered view and append that on your blade.