# Filtering in LARAVEL with checkboxes

Tags: php, laravel

I have a database filled with articles to create a baby webshop.
At this moment, all articles are shown on my webpage but I have a sidebar with a filter in it that gives the customer the option to choose between different categories, shops and to order the price by ascending or descending price.

How can I say to my foreach function to only show the articles that are called by the filter?

I can't use any external libraries like Jquery or Ajax to do this because school won't let us to..

Here is my code for my page:

```
<body class="relative min-h-screen">
    @include('partials.header')
        <main class="m-auto flex flex-row w-3/5">
            <div class="p-2 w-3/12 bg-red-100 mt-4 h-fit flex flex-col">
                <h3 class=" p-2 m-auto text-2xl w-10/12 border-b border-black ">Verfijnen</h3>
                <ul class="p-2 text-xl ">
                    <ul class="p-2">Categorieën
                        <div>
                            <form action="{{route('filter')}}" method="GET">
                            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                <li class="text-sm">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{$category->id}}" name="{{$category->id}}" value="{{ $category->title }}" onChange="this.form.submit()" {{ request()->filled($category->id) ? 'checked' :''}}>
                                    <label for="{{$category->id}}">{{ $category->title }}</label>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="p-2">Website
                        <div>
                            @foreach ($websites as $website)
                                <li class="text-sm">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{$website->id}}" name="{{$website->id}}" value="{{ $website->title }}">
                                    <label for="{{$website->id}}">{{ $website->title }}</label>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="p-2">Prijs
                        <div>
                            <li class="text-sm">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="LnH" name="LnH">
                                <label for="LnH">Laag naar Hoog</label>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-sm">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="HnL" name="HnL">
                                <label for="HnL">Hoog naar Laag</label>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="w-full p-8">
                <h3 class="text-center p-4">Overzicht</h3>
                <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-between gap-y-20 gap-x-2">
                    @foreach ($articles as $article)
                        <div class=" w-3/12 h-auto flex flex-col justify-between">
                            <div class="h-2/3 flex justify-center items-center">
                            <img src="{{$article->image}}" alt="" class="">
                            </div>
                                <div class="h-fit mt-2 ">
                                    <h4 class="text-md text-center"><strong>{{ $article->title }}</strong></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="">   
                                    <p class="mt-4">{{$article->prijs}}</p>
                                </div> 
                            </div>   
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    @include('partials.footer')
</body>
```

Comment: An ideea: use Javascript to submit the form on any change/checkbox. Reload same page keeping track of checked checkboxes.

Comment: Any link to an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel checkbox filter ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414103/laravel-checkbox-filter-ajax)

Comment: I'm not allowed to use ajax. I guess my teacher want me to use magic to do it..